# (Buffer Overflow Exploit) Can't overwrite $ebp and $eip registers

Tags: assembly, buffer, overflow, overwrite, eip

I am trying to exploit a C program with a Buffer Overflow.
The buffer's size is 44 bytes. (char buffer[44];).
I want to overwrite the $eip register with another address, but it seems that neither the $ebp register is being overwritten, nor the $eip. The program just bypasses them, and stars to fill in the addresses after the two registers and it doesn't even give a Segmentation Fault. What might be the problem? I post a photo with an input of 71 "A".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bufsize.h"

char grade = '3';
char Name[44];

void readString(char *s) {
   char buf[44];
   int i = 0;
   int c;

   while (1) {
      c = fgetc(stdin);
      if ((c == EOF) || (c == '\n'))
         break;
      buf[i++] = c;
   }
   buf[i] = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < 44; i++)
      s[i] = buf[i];

   return;
}

int main(void) {
   mprotect((void*)((unsigned int)Name & 0xfffff000), 1,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);

   printf("What is your name?\n");
   readString(Name);

   if (strcmp(Name, "Alex") == 0)
      grade = '6';

   printf("Thank you, %s.\n", Name);
   printf("I recommend that you get a grade of %c on this assignment.\n",
          grade);

   exit(0);
}
```

I want to edit the eip register so that it throws segmentation fault and later edit the eip to make the program print 6 without entering the string "Alex" as input. I put a breakpoint after the while(1) loop and with x/50x $esp I examine the memory addresses to see when the ebp and eip will be overwritten but the program bypasses them and continues to write to memory addresses further.

Comment: the memory content can't overwrite value in register on it's own => if you just overwrite the stack with some values, it doesn't do anything to the registers, until some instruction will actually use those values => it's unclear what you are trying and what you are asking. Include all important parts into your question: [MCVE]

Comment: Hi Ped7g, thanks for your reply! I just edited the post and posted more information. I hope it is clear to you now what I want to do. If it isn't, tell me to post more about it!

Comment: well, `ebp` and `esp` are CPU registers. They don't get overwritten by memory. Maybe you are trying to overwrite the part of stack, where you expect instructions like `pop ebp` `ret` to pick up those new values into `ebp+esp`, but that requires those instructions to be involved, and you posted only the C source, without instructions how to build it, and how you run it. Also in release compilation the `ebp` frame pointer may be omitted completely. You can run this in debugger, and put breakpoint at `buf[i] = 0;` instruction, input 71x 'A' and then check what happens next on the asm level.

Comment: BTW, the CPU stack and `ebp/esp` registers are not part of C abstract machine, so the compiler is free to compile your code in completely different way than you expect, as long as the result is correctly affecting the C abstract machine, i.e. from the user point of view it behaves as it should. Exploits like buffer overrun are attacking particular version of machine code, not particular C source. If you will build the C source with different compiler/options, it may need different exploit or even become not vulnerable at all, so in Q like this you may rather add the assembly view (C is bonus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just found a solution where I needed to put 44 * "A" and 8 * "5" and then the return address I wanted and it successfully changed, although the memory is like this:

-----[buffer][int c][int i][ebp][eip]-------

```
    44b    4b   4b   4b  4b
```

So, i insert at the 52 byte position ( 44 * "A" + 8 * "5") but it must be at position 56 normally. It works with 52, but i don't know why.

Comment: The 4bytes are for saving some registers before defining the local variables. Steps in case of callee-save are a) save previous ebp b) save caller registers, c) create local variables. check this [here](https://youtu.be/H4Z0S9ZbC0g?list=PL038BE01D3BAEFDB0&t=4638)